# Transform matrix on a scaled object

Tags: scripting, transforms

I have to create boxes, cylinders and spheres, to scale them and to rototranslate them in space by using a matrix transform. This is the code for a box:

```
myObj_TR = Matrix((
    (1, 0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0.707, 0.707, 0),
    (0, -0.707, 0.707, 0),
    (1, 0, 0, 1)))

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1,2,.3))

myObj = bpy.context.object
myObj.data.transform(myObj_TR)
myObj.data.update()
```

The problem is that in this way the box results sheared; it seems that the scaling is actually applied after the rototranslation.

I think that a workaround should be parenting my objects and then rototranslate the parent. Are there alternative ways?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying transformation at object level with `bpy.ops.transform.resize()` and on data level with `myObj.data.transform()`. The data transform is directly applied to vertices. The vertices' position simply is updated and the transformation is lost. When applying the transformation to the object the matrix is stored (if possible) in the translation, rotation and scale properties of the object. The object transform is applied on the vertex positions. In your case this results in `objMatrix @ dataMatrix` or `scaleMatrix @ locrotMatrix`.

You want to swap that order. I would advise you to **either** apply the transformation to the object **or** the data.

You can construct the final matrix separately first.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

mat_rot = Matrix([[1,  0,     0,     0],
                  [0,  0.707, 0.707, 0],
                  [0, -0.707, 0.707, 0],
                  [1,  0,     0,     1]])

mat_scale = Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 2, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 3, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]])

mat = mat_rot @ mat_scale
```

If you want to apply this matrix at the object level, use `object.matrix_world`.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
myObj = bpy.context.object
myObj.matrix_world = mat
```

If you want to apply this matrix at the data level, use `data.transform()`.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
myObj = bpy.context.object
myObj.data.transform(mat)
```

From the comments: If you don't import your matrix, but are constructing them from scratch, use the Helper constructors from the Matrix class, such as [`Matrix.Diagonal`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.Diagonal) or [`Matrix.Rotation`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.Rotation)

Comment: Worth noting:  `bpy.ops.transform...` applies on a data level when in edit mode. (on selected geometry).  There are nice constructors for matrices eg `R = Matrix.Rotation(radians(45), 4, 'X')`  and `S = Matrix.Diagonal((1, 2, 0.3)).to_4x4()`  _note element 3,3 in scale matrix is 1, not 0, could  create complications_